# Cocoa key value observing a key/entry in a dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, key-value-observing

Is it possible to observe a specific key in a dictionary? If so how can I do it?

Comment: By "observe" do you mean monitor for any changes?

Comment: +1 because that would be really useful

Comment: Did you try it?  It took me about 2 minutes to do so...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes (although it only makes sense to be observing an `NSMutableDictionary`).

```
@interface Foo : NSObject @end
@implementation Foo 

- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    NSLog(@"observing: -[%@ %@]", object, keyPath);
    NSLog(@"change: %@", change);
}

@end

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    Foo * f = [[Foo alloc] init];

    NSMutableDictionary * d = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [d addObserver:f forKeyPath:@"foo" options:0 context:NULL];
    [d setObject:@"bar" forKey:@"foo"];
    [d removeObjectForKey:@"foo"];
    [d removeObserver:f forKeyPath:@"foo"];
    [f release];

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Logs:

```
2010-12-21 17:39:53.758 EmptyFoundation[94589:a0f] observing: -[{
    foo = bar;
} foo]
2010-12-21 17:39:53.764 EmptyFoundation[94589:a0f] change: {
    kind = 1;
}
2010-12-21 17:39:53.765 EmptyFoundation[94589:a0f] observing: -[{
} foo]
2010-12-21 17:39:53.765 EmptyFoundation[94589:a0f] change: {
    kind = 1;
}
```

Comment: Very important: *"although it only makes sense to be observing an NSMutableDictionary"*. If you "change" the items in an NSDictionary (by creating a new NSDictionary) you'll lose the KVO on the objects in the former NSDictionary.